# Is there any open source GUI tool to monitor cassandra?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I would like to monitor cassandra database as well as need to check the values in the database.

Could any one suggest me best open source GUI tool ?

Regards,

Arun Raj.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Helenos:
https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos

It seems good

Answer (score 3):

To monitor - OpsCenter: http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-opscenter

To query - DevCenter: http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/devcenter

Comment: OpsCenter now only supports DataStax Enterprise.

Comment: Niether of the 2 DSE products above work on OSS cassandra. You have to be running DSE to use OpsCenter and DevCenter